# Windows Bluescreen - atikmpag.sys

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, bsod

### Information

Name: atikmpag.sys bluescreen (BSOD or BlueScreen of Death)

Error code: 0x00000116

Appears when: Playing games, watching videos

Can be reproduced: Yes

Cause: Graphics Card is the main assumption

### System Specifications

Before we begin - I will inform you of my specifications.

> OS: Windows 7 x64 Home Edition
>
> [Model](http://www.dell.com/au/p/inspiron-15r-5520/pd?oc=dv510611au&model_id=inspiron-15r-5520): Dell Inspiron 15R Special Edition (aka Inspiron 7520) (Add 2GB of RAM to the model linked)
>
> Hard Drive: 1TB
>
> CPU: Intel Quad-Core i7 Sandy Bridge (I think) Processor at 2.10GHz (I think it can be clocked to 3GHz?)
>
> RAM: 6GB (I think 1 x 4GB and 1 x 2GB)
>
> Display: 15.6" HD (1366x768)
>
> Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 7500M 2GB

### Details

So now that you know some basics about my computer, I'll get to the problem. Being an Ubuntu user I hardly use Windows, but occasionally I do. Like to run Skyrim and other games incompatible with Linux and WINE. The new Sims 3 Seasons patch is also now not supported. When playing these two games and other ones, theoretically. I have also heard others saying that while watching HD movies and video series it also happens.
While watching the bluescreen as it happens, I see it is the **'atikmpag.sys'** error.

I have not installed much and nothing significant. I think I have downloaded Skyrim, Firefox and The Sims 3. I haven't done much more... since Ubuntu is definitely the best in comparison! (No hate, just a joke :P). I can reproduce it easily (just by running a game for less than a minute). It is always there each time, but it's never at a specific time or anything.

So far I have found that it may be caused by lack of power to the graphics card, or it may be damaged or fried. Since I've had the computer for a mere 4 months (and have had *other* problems with it also). I have contacted Dell but they are useless beyond belief.

Anyone with any information, solutions or details are encouraged to share your knowledge, as it would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: 5 years later. ATI still creates blue screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start by updating your vid card driver (reinstall if its already latest). the faulting module is an ATI driver component as I'm sure you've surmised.

run 'dxdiag' (directX diagnostics) from the run bar or CLI. does it notice any issues? try reinstalling directX if problem still persists.

if no issues are found, and the problem continues, shut down all programs and run 'sfc.exe/SCANNOW' to check that all your system files are integral.

run an MS memory diagnostic. is all well?

last open the box while its off, and confirm that any PCIe power rails to the card are connected. does your card have any power slots that your PSU does not have a rail for? 
Turn the box on. does the vidcard fan start spinning quickly as expected? no rattling or anything?

start turning down any advanced vidcard features (AA, textures, VSynch, etc) and see where that leads you. if you turn your game graphics down to minimum, does the problem still occure at about the same time into the game?

if all that fails, my next step would be to rebuild the OS with latest drivers and DX, and see if its still reproducible. if so, replace your vid card. if not, then you are fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up uninstalling Windows, but I'll mark this as best answer because it may be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

[Bug Check 0x116: VIDEO_TDR_ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

0x116 bugcheks are hard to debug, because the public symbols don't include all data. 
You can try to use the [AMD Catalyst 12.11 Beta driver](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst1211betadriver.aspx) and hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I have heard it could also be caused by the graphics card not being installed correctly. Is that true? I'll try the driver though.

Comment: this is mostly a driver issue or a hardware failure (PSU, GPU itself). Try the driver and look if this fixes it.